# How to push data from vue to external js script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I use code below I'm getting error that istance this.message doesn't exist, but when I will push **this** as **self** to MyFunction(self), it will work good. So, the question is how can I push **this** to my JS file/function without using arguments of function from Vue?

```
import { MyFunction } from "./Functions/HelpFunctions.js";
data(){
   return{
       message: 'Hello World'
   }
}
methods: {
   MyFunction: MyFunction
},

created(){
   this.MyFunction();
}
```

JS file :

```
export const MyFunction  = () => {
    console.log(this.message); 
}
```

This cod works if I call it in Vue with pushing this:

```
export const MyFunction = (self) => {
    console.log(self.message); 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `this.msg` since that's how you defined it in `data()`?

Comment: @Phil yes, but not in external JS script, which I imported

Comment: So where exactly is `this.message` supposed to come from? No matter where it's defined `msg` is not `message`

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, it's just a typo

Comment: Your external functions should not have a dependency on `this` since that is only ever defined where and how the function is called. Instead, specify all the required parameters for the function, in this case a string `message`... `MyFunction () { MyFunction(this.message) }`